# OpenFOAM blockMesh cylindrical mesh and its paraFoam plotting face normals

Tags: mesh, paraview, normals, fipy, openfoam

**OpenFOAM section:**

I have meshed a hollow cylinder shape in OpenFOAM. In this model, flow will be flow from outer cylinder wall to the inner cylinder wall; Right-Hand law is used for meshing points as below:
[image]
I have tried to plot face normals by OpenFOAM compiled paraFoam, but I couldn't. It is possible to plot boundary mesh faces (which are on top, bottom, inner and outer cylinder walls) by Glyph normals, but not the internal mesh faces.

**Q OpenFOAM:** Is there any function code or way to plot them inside paraFoam?

Mesh file have been exported to be plotted inside python, as above right picture. As it is obvious, in this way, mesh faces on Start-End overlapping plane have opposite directions comparing to the other rotational face normals.

**Q OpenFOAM:** Do these face normal directions result in wrong results? or results are controlled, only, by Right-Hand rule? Is there any code or way to change these directions, if it is needed?

> *Note: I have imported this mesh file into python FiPy by Gmsh3D and used its faceNormals and cellCenters to plot the face normals by matplotlib.*

**FiPy section:**

I have changed the clockwise Start-End mesh face normals direction to counterclockwise by the following code, due to my needs to use counterclockwise faceNormals direction:

```
for i in range(self.mesh.numberOfCells):
    for f in self.mesh.cellFaceIDs.data.T[i]:
        if self.mesh.faceCenters().T[f][0] > 0 > self.mesh.faceNormals.T[f][1] and self.mesh.faceCenters().T[f][1] == 0:
            self.mesh.faceNormals.T[f] = np.multiply(np.array([-1, -1, 1]), self.mesh.faceNormals.T[f])
```

**Q FiPy:** Do these face normal direction changes have any effect on FiPy solving results?
As I understood it from the recent [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66902218/fipy-calcnormals-function) *(I couldn't ask this question there duo to not having enough reputation quorum)*, FiPy considers cell faceNormal direction of a shared face outward to its corresponding neighbor cell, and faceNormal directions (which are shown in the picture using FiPy mesh.FaceNormals) have no effect on the solution, by themselves; This means that it can be considered in opposite directions by the solver depending on the circumstances. Is it right?? Is there any FiPy mesh modules to create such O'grid cylindrical type meshing system, in which x, y, and z coordinates of the nodes could be available? I have tried 'CylindricalGrid2D' for radial meshing, but it gives only r and z coordinates of the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding resetting the values of the `faceNormals` with FiPy. That might not be possible depending on the type of mesh. For example, with a `Grid2D` style mesh that would result in `AttributeError: can't set attribute` as the normals are calculated when required rather than stored in the mesh object. If it is possible it most likely breaks FiPy though. For example, the following gives very different results when the `faceNormals` are randomly flipped.

```
from fipy import CellVariable, Grid3D, DiffusionTerm
from fipy.meshes.mesh import Mesh
import numpy as np

grid = Grid3D(nx=3, ny=3, nz=1)

mesh = Mesh(grid.vertexCoords, grid.faceVertexIDs, grid.cellFaceIDs)

var = CellVariable(mesh=mesh)

var.constrain(1, where=mesh.facesLeft)
var.constrain(0, where=mesh.facesRight)

DiffusionTerm().solve(var)
print(var)

var[:] = 0.0

flip = 2 * np.random.randint(2, size=mesh.faceNormals.shape[1]) - 1
mesh.faceNormals[:] = mesh.faceNormals * flip[None]

DiffusionTerm().solve(var)
print(var)
```

Comment: This answer is for a part of the question that was later removed from the original post.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have removed that part because I thought it is better to ask by fipy group list. I have added again here that part.

Comment: By randomly flipping, it most likely result in wrong answers, by any mesh type. In your example, it must be limited to interior faces, as my problem, (as I meant what I called 'shared faces'). Using ```[mesh.faceNormals.T[face][:] == mesh.faceNormals.T[face] * flip[face] for face in mesh.interiorFaceIDs]``` could give true answers. For the Start-End overlapping plane, z magnitude remains constant (cylinder axis is along z) but x and y was changed to -x and -y. So, the normal vector magnitudes will remain constant, but oppositely signed (normal vectors mirrored on corresponding faces).

Comment: From your explanation and as mr. Guyer's advise, it is more logical to initialize a faceVariable with faceNormals to avoid possible unwanted wrong results.

Answer (score 1):

> FiPy considers faceNormal direction of a shared face outward to the neighbor cell,

No, as stated in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66902218/fipy-calcnormals-function) you posted, FiPy considers the faceNormal direction to be into the second of the two cells bounding a face. A neighbor cell is relative to a cell. A face has two bounding cells; if the face is on the exterior, then both bounding cells are the same.

> and faceNormal directions (which are shown in the picture using FiPy mesh.FaceNormals) have no effect on the solution, by themselves; This means that it can be considered in opposite directions by the solver depending on the circumstances. Is it right??

No. As demonstrated in the answer posted by @wd15, FiPy uses the `faceNormal` internally and expects it to obey the conventions we have defined, i.e., that it always points into the second cell.

There's nothing stopping you from initializing a `FaceVariable` with `faceNormals` and then overriding some values as you see fit:

```py
my_normals = fp.FaceVariable(mesh=mesh, value=mesh.faceNormals, rank=1)
my_normals.setValue(my_desired_orientation, where=my_backward_faces)
```

> Is there any FiPy mesh modules to create such O'grid cylindrical type meshing system, in which x, y, and z coordinates of the nodes could be available?

No.

Comment: One of my aims of the question was to understand that if the mentioned clockwise face normals on the Start-End overlapping plane (which are not on the exterior, are given by mesh.faceNormals, and have opposite direction comparing to others) can affect the final results or cannot. It was understood that, direction of the given normal vectors by 'mesh.faceNormals' doesn't affect the results, by themselves, and will be directed in the same direction or opposite direction by FiPy based on the conventions. For the first part of the answer, that was what I meant; I changed the sentence more clearly.